# Dynamic DOM elements add/remove with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have started to learn Vue.js and i can't figure it out how would you do this in Vue.js like I did it with jQuery:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<h2>jQuery</h2>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r1">
    <td><input name="item[]" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" type="number"/></td>
    <td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

.js

```
// jQuery
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(){
    var row = parseInt($('#t1 tr:last-child').attr('id')) + 1;
    alert(row);
        $('#t1').append('<tr id="r'+row+'"><td><input name="item[]" type="text"/></td><td><input name="quantity[]" type="number"/></td><td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
        var row = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
    $('#r'+row).remove();
});
```

How to create a whole new element on a click with Vue and how to remove it?

Here is all loaded in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/17736/)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

VueJS is data driven, so forget on direct DOM manipulations.

In example below, you will see that I've defined the `inputs` array - that's the place where would we store all rows - so it would be array of objects.

In our template we're iterating through the `inputs` array and for each input we send index too - required for row deleting.

`addRow` is method push new object to our `inputs` array (with predefined schema), and give it unique index.

Here is the example: http://jsbin.com/zusokiy/edit?html,js,output

Template:

```
  <div id="app">

    <ul>
      <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
        <input type="text" v-model="input.one"> - {{ input.one }}  
        <input type="text" v-model="input.two"> - {{ input.two }}
        <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button @click="addRow">Add row</button>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    inputs: []
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        one: '',
        two: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }

})
```

Better option would be maybe break it into components, but this is so far, so good.

Comment: it works...but why did you change the table and tr tag into ul and li...does it matter?

Comment: it seems to me that it doesn't = http://jsbin.com/padecawido/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just use the quicker way :)

Comment: Is the word `inputs` some kind of a keyword in vue?

Comment: I don't think so, but not sure - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/compiler/error-detector.js

Comment: No it's not. it was my mistake....i changed that word and it didn't work but now i know how does this thing work, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Is this valid for Vue 3?

Comment: Thanks @BelminBedak: "VueJS is data driven, so forget on direct DOM manipulations" - made it all click for me and reduced by code by 75%. I'm liking Vue!