# In VueJS after append() an element the click method not works

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can solve this problem in jquery using the method `$(document).on('click', '.newButton', function(){});` how can I solve the same thing at VUE

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    oldButton: function () {
      $('#app').append('<button v-on:click="newButton">The New Button</button>');
    },
    
    newButton: function () {
      console.log('Hello World!');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="oldButton">The Old Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508040/dynamic-dom-elements-add-remove-with-vue) hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an array of buttons:

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    btns: []
  },

  methods: {
    addBtn() {
      this.btns.push({
         name: 'Dynamic Button'
      })
    },
    showMsg(index) {
      console.log('Hello World!, from Button ' + index)
   }
  }

})
```

And:

```
<div id="app">    
  <ul>
     <li v-for="(btn, index) in btns">
        <button  @click="showMsg(index)" type="text"> {{ btn.name}}</button>             
     </li>
  </ul>    
<button @click="addBtn">Add Button</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I think

Answer (score 4):

In vue.js, you normally don't manipulate DOM in javascript; If you want to conditionally show a component, you can use [`v-if` or `v-show` directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html); And also you should define your functions as `methods` instead of `data`:

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showNewButton: false
  },
  methods: {
    oldButton: function () {
      this.showNewButton = true;
    },
    
    newButton: function () {
      console.log('Hello World!');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="oldButton">The Old Button</button>
  <button v-if="showNewButton" v-on:click="newButton">The New Button</button>
</div>
```