# Is it good to access DOM in vue js?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I want to know is it OK to access DOM in a Vue js application?
For example, if I want to append an element (div) to body tag is this recommended to use `document.getElementById` in a Vue js method?

I have no data that can be used to make or remove elements based on data.
I really just want to know is it common to use `document` to access DOM in Vue js?

Something like this :

```
methods:{
 appendToBody(){
   let node = document.createElement("div");
   document.getElementById("#body").appendChild(node);
 }
}
```

Comment: why not you are using component?

Comment: how can i append a div to body by using components? i think vue js can just control #app element not the body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic DOM elements add/remove with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508040/dynamic-dom-elements-add-remove-with-vue)

Comment: @stdob-- no it couldn't help me. There is no data that i want to add or remove elements based on that data. i just want add an element to body out side of vue js instance(i mean #application section)

Comment: Why you need this ? what is your use case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what part of the DOM you are referring too.

If you want to change the subtree that is handled by Vue, you **shouldn't do that**. You should rely on reactive properties, [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), components. If you need to access an DOM element that is a child of the current component you can use [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

If you need to change a part of the DOM which is outside of Vue's realm then by all means do it.

In your case is not clear what you want to achieve and is hard to give a clear answer.

Comment: Thank You! I think my case is third one.Because i want to do some works out side of Vue js instance.

Comment: As a side note, how bad is it to modify the dom within a Vue instance. I'm integrating Vue into an existing app, and have Vue control the header, side bar, and main content div, but then the existing app is currently using jQuery to change views and control everything within that dom element. Is that ok? Its not great obviously, but can I allow a blackbox situation in there? I will post as new question if I have to, but thought I would ask as related.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ok. If you're asking if it will work, it will. You need to be careful in splitting the responsibilities between Vue and JQuery. It could work nicely as long as you don't rely on Vue to do anything related to that DOM element. Trying to control it by both vue and jquery is gonna prove to be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM functions like `document.getElementById` in Vue to find elements, but never use DOM functions to change the DOM. Always do modifications within Vue by changing variables and react to it in the template.

Comment: "*never use DOM functions to change the DOM*" that might be correct for the root DOM element that the Vue instance is managing and its children. Outside of that, you can certainly change the DOM.

Comment: @edwin and u think is it ok that i use this function in vue js like this?
`document.body.appendChild(node);` is it a modification or changing?

Comment: Yes, `appendChild()` is a modification, don't do that in you Vue app. And str is right that it is no problem to change elements outside your Vue app.